# How do you create the correct Lambda expression to handle comparing 2 object lists?

Tags: c#, lambda

I have a `List<imports>` which is created by reading a CSV file.  I have a `List<table>` by reading from a database table.  What would be the correct way of setting up lambda expressions to:

- Find the intersection *(Records to UPDATE or Records with NO ACTION)*
- Find the new items in List *(Records to INSERT)*
- Find the items in List **not** in List *(Records to DELETE)*

Right now I am muscling my way through this like:

```
foreach (DTO.ImportData row in Helper.ImportTracker.ImportsValid)
{
    bool isInsert = false;
    bool isUpdate = false;
    Model.Auto auto = null;

    // Get auto(s) for this SKU + VIN + ClientID...
    var autos = _dbFeed.Autoes.Where(a => a.StockNumber == row.Stock && a.VIN == row.VIN && a.ClientID == _targetClientID && a.SourceClientID == _sourceClientID).ToList();
    if (autos.Count > 1)        // ERROR...
    {
        Helper.ImportTracker.ImportsInvalid.Add(row);
        continue;
    }
    else if (autos.Count == 1)  // UPDATE...
    {
        auto = autos[0];
        if (auto.GuaranteedSalePrice != row.GuaranteedSalePrice ||
            auto.ListPrice != row.ListPrice ||
            auto.Miles != row.Miles ||
            auto.Active != row.Active ||
            auto.MSRP != row.MSRP ||
            auto.InternetPrice != row.Internet_Price ||
            auto.InvoiceCost != row.Invoice ||
            auto.Make != row.Make ||
            auto.Model != row.Model ||
            auto.Year != row.Year 
            )
        {
            Helper.ImportTracker.Updates.Add(row);
            isUpdate = true;
        }
        else
        {
            isUpdate = false;
            auto = null;
        }
    }
    else                        // INSERT...
    {
        isInsert = true;
        auto = new Model.Auto();
        _dbFeed.Autoes.AddObject(auto);
        Helper.ImportTracker.Inserts.Add(row);
    }

    // Fill in the data...
    if (auto != null)
    {
        ...
    }
    // left out for readability - this section just maps the import 
    // data to the table row and saves to the DB...
}
```

The above section handles the first 2 cases I listed at the beginning.

I am having a dickens of a time wrapping my head around the correct way to put lambdas together for this.

I realize I may have to convert all of my `List<import>` to `List<table>` so that I can compare apples to apples and that is not a problem.  I am also thinking I need to write a custom comparer along the lines of:

```
class TableComparer : IEqualityComparer<table>
{
    public bool Equals(table x, table y)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) ||
            Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            return x.SKU == y.SKU && x.VIN == y.VIN && x.ClientID == y.ClientID;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(table table)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(table, null)) return 0;

        int hashSKU = SKU == null ? 0 : SKU.GetHashCode();
        int hashVIN = VIN == null ? 0 : VIN.GetHashCode();
        int hashClientID = ClientID.GetHashCode();

        return hashClientID ^ hashSKU ^ hashVIN;
    }
}
```

Then I can do:

```
var UpdateAutos = autos.Intersect(new TableComparer(imports));
var InsertAutos = imports.Except(new TableComparer(autos));
var DeleteAutos = autos.Except(new TableComparer(imports));
```

And now my head is spinning!  ;)

Am I on the right track?

---

ADDITIONAL INFO:
So far I am this far with my new code:

```
private void HandleAutos()
{
    // convert to List<auto>...
    List<Model.Auto> imports = AutoConvert.Convert(Helper.ImportTracker.ImportsValid, _targetClientID, _sourceClientID, DateTime.UtcNow, _dbFeed);

    // get all DB records in List<auto>...
    List<Model.Auto> current = _dbFeed.Autoes.Where(a => a.ClientID == _targetClientID && a.Active == true).ToList();

    // isolate all Inserts, Updates and Deletes...
    var intersect = imports.Intersect(current, new AutoIsIn());         // should be all autos with matching VIN & SKU  //
    var updates = intersect.Intersect(current, new AutoHasChanged());   // should be a subset of changed resords        //
    var inserts = imports.Except(current, new AutoIsIn());              // should be all the imports not in the DB      //
    var deletes = current.Except(imports, new AutoIsIn());              // should be all the DB records not in imports  //

}
```

And my Comparer class looks like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace RivWorks.FeedHandler.Library
{
    class AutoIsIn : IEqualityComparer<Model.Auto>
    {
        public bool Equals(Model.Auto x, Model.Auto y)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

            return x.StockNumber == y.StockNumber && x.VIN == y.VIN;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Model.Auto auto)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(auto, null)) return 0;

            int hashSKU = auto.StockNumber == null ? 0 : auto.StockNumber.GetHashCode();
            int hashVIN = auto.VIN == null ? 0 : auto.VIN.GetHashCode();

            return hashSKU ^ hashVIN;
        }
    }

    class AutoHasChanged : IEqualityComparer<Model.Auto>
    {
        public bool Equals(Model.Auto x, Model.Auto y)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null)) return false;

            return (x.GuaranteedSalePrice != y.GuaranteedSalePrice 
                 || x.ListPrice != y.ListPrice 
                 || x.Miles != y.Miles 
                 || x.MSRP != y.MSRP 
                 || x.InternetPrice != y.InternetPrice 
                 || x.InvoiceCost != y.InvoiceCost 
                 || x.Make != y.Make 
                 || x.Model != y.Model 
                 || x.Year != y.Year
                 );
        }

        public int GetHashCode(Model.Auto auto)
        {
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(auto, null)) return 0;

            int hashMake = auto.Make == null ? 0 : auto.Make.GetHashCode();
            int hashModel = auto.Model == null ? 0 : auto.Model.GetHashCode();
            int hashYear = auto.Year.GetHashCode();

            int hashGSP = auto.GuaranteedSalePrice.GetHashCode();
            int hashLP = !auto.ListPrice.HasValue ? 0 : auto.ListPrice.GetHashCode();
            int hashMiles = !auto.Miles.HasValue ? 0 : auto.Miles.GetHashCode();
            int hashMSRP = !auto.MSRP.HasValue ? 0 : auto.MSRP.GetHashCode();
            int hashIP = !auto.InternetPrice.HasValue ? 0 : auto.InternetPrice.GetHashCode();
            int hashIC = !auto.InvoiceCost.HasValue ? 0 : auto.InvoiceCost.GetHashCode();

            return hashMake ^ hashModel ^ hashYear ^ hashGSP ^ hashLP ^ hashMiles ^ hashMSRP ^ hashIP ^ hashIC;
        }
    }
}
```

Anything amiss so far?

-kb

Comment: It seems you're on the right track. It would be preferable to load your records into the same entity/DTO to allow for simple manipulation. I don't have a code sample to hand so won't post as an answer but you can extend lambdas to combine multiple lambdas in AND/OR syntax. This can be very handy. If you want it, I'll try to dig it out.

Comment: That would be awesome.  I do understand using the same entities/DTOs which is why I am looking at creating an IEqualityComparer for this (as I am on EF2 or EF3 and not EF4)...

Comment: As an aside, I did up a simple console app to play with Intersect, Except, etc and am not quite getting the results I expected.  Suffice it to say I am still in the steep part of the learning curve for Lambdas outside of simple LINQ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution to OPs problem but in response to OPs comments...

```
Public Module ExpressionExtensions

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function Compose(Of T)(ByVal first As Expressions.Expression(Of T), ByVal second As Expressions.Expression(Of T), ByVal merge As Func(Of Expressions.Expression, Expressions.Expression, Expressions.Expression)) As Expressions.Expression(Of T)

        ' build parameter map (from parameters of second to parameters of first)
        Dim map = first.Parameters.[Select](Function(f, i) New With {f, .s = second.Parameters(i)}).ToDictionary(Function(p) p.s, Function(p) p.f)

        ' replace parameters in the second lambda expression with parameters from the first
        Dim secondBody = ParameterRebinder.ReplaceParameters(map, second.Body)

        ' apply composition of lambda expression bodies to parameters from the first expression 
        Return Expressions.Expression.Lambda(Of T)(merge(first.Body, secondBody), first.Parameters)
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [And](Of T)(ByVal first As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal second As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return first.Compose(second, AddressOf Expressions.Expression.And)
    End Function

    <System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Extension()> _
    Public Function [Or](Of T)(ByVal first As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean)), ByVal second As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))) As Expressions.Expression(Of Func(Of T, Boolean))
        Return first.Compose(second, AddressOf Expressions.Expression.[Or])
    End Function

End Module
```

**Edit:** Added Missing ParameterRebinder

```
Public Class ParameterRebinder
    Inherits Expressions.ExpressionVisitor

    Private ReadOnly map As Dictionary(Of Expressions.ParameterExpression, Expressions.ParameterExpression)

    Public Sub New(ByVal map As Dictionary(Of Expressions.ParameterExpression, Expressions.ParameterExpression))
        Me.map = If(map, New Dictionary(Of Expressions.ParameterExpression, Expressions.ParameterExpression)())
    End Sub

    Public Shared Function ReplaceParameters(ByVal map As Dictionary(Of Expressions.ParameterExpression, Expressions.ParameterExpression), ByVal exp As Expressions.Expression) As Expressions.Expression
        Return New ParameterRebinder(map).Visit(exp)
    End Function

    Protected Overloads Overrides Function VisitParameter(ByVal p As Expressions.ParameterExpression) As Expressions.Expression
        Dim replacement As Expressions.ParameterExpression = Nothing
        If map.TryGetValue(p, replacement) Then
            p = replacement
        End If
        Return MyBase.VisitParameter(p)
    End Function
End Class
```

The above allows you to Have...

```
Dim A as System.Func(Of MyType, Boolean) = Function(x) x.SomeField = SomeValue
Dim B as System.Func(Of MyType, Boolean) = A.Or(Function(x) x.SomeOtherField = SomeOtherValue)
Dim C as System.Func(Of MyType, Boolean) = A.And(Function(x) x.SomeOtherField = SomeOtherValue)
```

I've explicitly typed the above for clarity. It's not required.

Apologies for being in VB - I've got the code to hand and don't have time to translate right now

Comment: Thanks.  Looking through this over the next couple of days.  And don't worry about the VB, I am bi-lingual.  ;)

Comment: @Keith No worries, hope it helps. I've just realised I didn't include the `ParameterRebinder` class - I've edit my answer to include it. Let me know if you have any problems

Comment: ok - I thought I knew enough.  Would it be difficult for you to translate it to C#?

Comment: And this would allow me to pass in my 2 objects (one empty) and copy everything from the full to the empty?

Comment: Yeah, I use that a lot but it tends to choke on code with Lambdas - I also use [this one](http://converter.telerik.com/) Which supports .Net 4 and lambdas but is a little stricter